# Can't type ç on some programs

Tags: debian, input-languages, telegram-messenger

I've configured the language on my Debian 8 keyboard to US, international with dead keys, and in some programs I can type **ç** by doing <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd>. For example, Iceweasel works. But on telegram it won't... What can be the cause? When I try it on telegram, it gives me **ć**. I tried to change the language of telegram to english but it didn't help, and also it's not only telegram that it happens

Answer (score 0):

With that layout you can compose a **ç** with  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

[image]